# limit a user to only input values if it's in a previously given list

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

i'm trying to make the user only pick values from a list and if he picks other values outside the list I want the code to ask again for the correct value

my attempt :

```
accepted_values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
while True:
            
    print('Enter two numbers from the list :', accepted_values)
    first_num = input("Enter first_num: ")
    second_num = input("Enter second_num: ")
    userinput = []
    userinput.append(int(first_num))
    userinput.append(int(second_num))
    if userinput not in accepted_values:
        print('please enter numbers from this range:', accepted_values)
        continue
    else:
        break
```

but it results in a loop of it asking me to enter the correct values even if I enter a correct number

Comment: hint, what does `[1, 2] in accepted_values` return?

Comment: Was going to suggest `set`, but `any` is probably easier: `if any(num not in accepted_values for num in userinput): ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to check if `[1, 2]` is in `accepted_values` list. The integers `1` and `2` are SEPERATLY but the literal list `[1, 2]` isn't. Below is a way around it:

```py
accepted_values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    while True:
        print('Enter two numbers from the list :', accepted_values)
        first_num = input("Enter first_num: ")
        second_num = input("Enter second_num: ")
        userinput = []
        userinput.append(int(first_num))
        userinput.append(int(second_num))

        # Using "any"
        if any(num not in accepted_values for num in userinput):

            print('please enter numbers from this range:', accepted_values)
            continue
        else:
            break
```

Using the `any` statement, you can sort of iterate through the user input while checking if its in accepted values.

Answer (score 2):

You are checking if the entire list `userinput` is an element of `accepted_values`. So that means it checks whether `[input1, input2]` is in `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` instead of asking whether `input1` and `input2` are in `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`. The simplest way to correct it is to change  `if userinput not in accepted_values:` to `if userinput[0] not in accepted_values or userinput[1] not in accepted_values:`.

Comment: I think you meant to use `or` in your final line in your answer.

Comment: ah yes, mistakes were made

Answer (score 1):

I see perfect usecase for python sets here. Something like this will fit your needs perfectly:

```
>>> accepted_values = [1,2,3,4]
>>> user_input = [1,4]
>>> set(user_input) <= set(accepted_values )
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your condition checking is wrong. Here is a solution to check by using set:

```
if not (set(userinput).issubset(set(accepted_values))):
```

If the above condition is `True`, means userinput is not a subset of accepted_values.

Answer (score 0):

just move your append method to the else statement:

```
accepted_values = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
while True:
    
    print('Enter two numbers from the list :', accepted_values)
    first_num = input("Enter first_num: ")
    second_num = input("Enter second_num: ")
    
    if first_num not in accepted_values or second_num not in accepted_values:
        print('please enter numbers from this range:', accepted_values)
        continue
    else:
        userinput = []
        userinput.append(int(first_num))
        userinput.append(int(second_num))
        break
```